# How can I create a Managed Server on a different machine?

Tags: weblogic12c

I am trying to create a second managed server on mine OSB domain, but due to the specification that you can see below I am not being able to do it.

[image]

I have installed on Machine 2 the following package:
fmw_12.2.1.4.0_infrastructure.jar
fmw_12.2.1.4.0_osb.jar

On the domain creation I selected the nodemanager per domain.

Since my Domain is installed on a shared FS, which steps I should follow in order to create a Managed Server on Machine 1 for my OSB domain?

Best Regards.

Comment: Create the Machine 1 and the ManagedServer_1 in your domain configuration using the admin console or WLST. Then, just start your server.

Comment: which node manager should I put in machine1? the one that is running on machine 2?

Comment: You will configure 2 machines in your domain.
You start a nodemanager instance on each machine.
It is a "per domain" nodemanager nut you need to run one instance on each machine.